# ScrollView wont scroll Completely

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface, scrollview

I'm trying to make a layout divided into two parts in which the lower part should be scrollable.But the scrollview wont scroll completely till the end.

I have tried using NestedScrollView.I have also already tried adding margins and padding to scrollview, constraint layout, last view in the scroll view.Button at the end is not reachable. view abruptly ends in the middle of the textview above that button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".mainClusterActivity"
android:id="@+id/const1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Seen" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/searchedCheckBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchedCheckBoxId"
        android:text="Learnt" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/learnedCheckBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/learnedCheckBoxId"
        android:text="Mark" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/markedCheckBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv3" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wordTvId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="WORD!"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tempBarTv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wordTvId"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tempBarTv"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/meaningTempId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Meaning"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/meaningLvId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/meaningTempId" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temp2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Synonyms"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/meaningLvId"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.069"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/SynonymsLvId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="Meaning"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temp2" />

        <TextView
           android:id="@+id/temp1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="Synonyms with Seached Words"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SynonymsLvId"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.069"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/SynonymsWithSearchedLvId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="Meaning"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temp1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notesTempTvId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="Notes"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SynonymsWithSearchedLvId" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notesTvId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:text="Notes"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notesTempTvId" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addNotesId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_rounded_rect"
            android:text="EDIT NOTES!"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notesTvId"
            />



    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

   </ScrollView>

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT: I changed the parent constraint layout to relative layout and it works perfectly fine now. Still no idea why it didn't before. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I was also facing same problem some days ago. I was using scrollview and inside it i was using relativelayout and i kept gravity of it to center.that was the problem in my case. So, i suggest you to try this out. change your scrollview child(constraint layout) to relative layout and don't asign its gravity and try it. May be it will work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--I have commented where you have to change and why. do all mention changes. it will work fine-->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/const1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Seen" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/searchedCheckBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/searchedCheckBoxId"
        android:text="Learnt" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/learnedCheckBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/learnedCheckBoxId"
        android:text="Mark" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/markedCheckBoxId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv3" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wordTvId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="WORD!"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout2" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tempBarTv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wordTvId" />

 <!-- Add app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 And also set width and Height to 0dp so scrollView will take rest screen height.-->
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tempBarTv">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/meaningTempId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:text="Meaning"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/meaningLvId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.488"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/meaningTempId" />

        <!--This textView is having wrong id if you have not defined into resource. There is + sign is missing or define id into resource-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temp2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Synonyms"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.069"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/meaningLvId" />

        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/SynonymsLvId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="Meaning"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temp2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temp1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Synonyms with Seached Words"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.069"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SynonymsLvId" />

        <ListView

            android:id="@+id/SynonymsWithSearchedLvId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="Meaning"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/temp1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notesTempTvId"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Notes"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/SynonymsWithSearchedLvId" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notesTvId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_rect_shape"
            android:text="Notes"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notesTempTvId" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addNotesId"
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/red_rounded_rect"
            android:text="EDIT NOTES!"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/notesTvId" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```